# Sorting dates in a textfile

Tags: sorting, powershell

I am sorting the text file which has the following pattern:

```
moon|gamma|D5412|745|72|8:3:43:7:6:2016
Bingo|denmark|4|4|985|12:11:43:7:12:2015
charlie|london|Debb|517|10|7:15:43:6:5:2014
Alpha|Debra|devido|0|8745|6:33:43:23:6:2016
```

Considering the `7:3:43:7:6:2016` substring as a date in each line, I need to sort the lines in ascending or descending order of dates.
I am getting errors and I am unable to sort text file.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to split the string by the delimiter `|` and grab the last value from each line:

```
# Index -1 is always the last one
$dateString = 'moon|gamma|D5412|745|72|8:3:43:7:6:2016'.Split('|')[-1]
```

You can then use the `DateTime.ParseExact()` static method to parse the input string as a sortable `DateTime` object:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact($dateString,'H:m:s:d:M:yyyy',[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Now we just need to put that together as an argument to `Sort-Object -Property`:

```
Get-Content .\file.txt |Sort-Object -Property { [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Split('|')[-1],'H:m:s:d:M:yyyy',[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)}
```

Default sort order of `Sort-Object` is ascending, use the `-Descending` switch to change it around if need be.

---

If you want to use a more terse and unix'y approach, sort on the individual values of the date string instead (you'll need to reorder them though):

```
Sort-Object { $_.Split('|')[-1].Split(':')[5,4,3,0,1,2] }
```

Comment: It's giving many errors maybe I am not using it properly while reading the file or parsing the text.

Comment: @maverick Update your question and add the error(s) you get. If the file is formatted exactly as you describe both methods should work